# How to use arc land with a git-svn repository?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, arcanist

There is a svn repository located in `https://host:port/codebase/project`, without `tags` or `branches` subdirectories. Normally using with SVN, people `svn checkout https://host:port/codebase/project` to get working copy, and using `arc diff` and `arc commit` to lunch a code-review or commit changes onto remote SVN server.

I `git svn clone https://host:port/codebase/project` the repository recently, and got a Git working copy. After coding on the branch named `dev-foo`, I used `arc diff` to start a code-review. Arcanist reported an error when I was `arc land`ing the commits on the branch `dev-foo`, which had passed the code-review.

```sh
Landing current branch 'master'.
 TARGET  Landing onto "master", the default target under git.
 REMOTE  Using remote "origin", the default remote under Git.
 Exception 
No pushable remote "origin" exists. Use the "--remote" flag to choose a valid, pushable remote to land changes onto.
(Run with `--trace` for a full exception trace.)
```

`arc land --trace` showed more information, but still did not help me:

```sh
 ARGV  '/home/user/.local/opt/arcanist/bin/../scripts/arcanist.php' 'land' '--trace'
 LOAD  Loaded "phutil" from "/home/user/.local/opt/libphutil/src".
 LOAD  Loaded "arcanist" from "/home/user/.local/opt/arcanist/src".
Config: Reading user configuration file "/home/user/.arcrc"...
Config: Did not find system configuration at "/etc/arcconfig".
Working Copy: Unable to find .arcconfig in any of these locations: /home/user/gitrepo/project/.arcconfig.
Working Copy: Path "/home/user/gitrepo/project" is part of `git` working copy "/home/user/gitrepo/project".
Working Copy: Project root is at "/home/user/gitrepo/project".
Config: Did not find local configuration at "/home/user/gitrepo/project/.git/arc/config".
>>> [0] (+0) <http> http://phab.host/api/user.whoami
<<< [0] (+1,872) <http> 1,871,961 us
>>> [1] (+1,876) <exec> $ git symbolic-ref --quiet HEAD
<<< [1] (+1,884) <exec> 7,125 us
>>> [2] (+1,885) <exec> $ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name 'master'@{upstream}
<<< [2] (+1,892) <exec> 6,814 us
>>> [3] (+1,892) <exec> $ git --version
<<< [3] (+1,898) <exec> 6,057 us
>>> [4] (+1,899) <exec> $ git ls-remote --get-url 'origin'
<<< [4] (+1,905) <exec> 6,534 us
>>> [5] (+1,906) <exec> $ git symbolic-ref --quiet HEAD
<<< [5] (+1,913) <exec> 6,532 us
Landing current branch 'master'.
>>> [6] (+1,914) <exec> $ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name 'master'@{upstream}
<<< [6] (+1,921) <exec> 6,660 us
>>> [7] (+1,921) <exec> $ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name 'master'@{upstream}
<<< [7] (+1,928) <exec> 6,803 us
>>> [8] (+1,929) <exec> $ git symbolic-ref --quiet HEAD
<<< [8] (+1,936) <exec> 6,536 us
>>> [9] (+1,939) <exec> $ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name 'master'@{upstream}
<<< [9] (+1,946) <exec> 6,509 us
 TARGET  Landing onto "master", the default target under git.
>>> [10] (+1,947) <exec> $ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name 'master'@{upstream}
<<< [10] (+1,954) <exec> 6,478 us
>>> [11] (+1,954) <exec> $ git rev-parse --git-dir
<<< [11] (+1,961) <exec> 6,400 us
 REMOTE  Using remote "origin", the default remote under Git.
>>> [12] (+1,961) <exec> $ git remote get-url --push -- 'origin'
<<< [12] (+1,968) <exec> 6,300 us

[2020-01-16 13:39:03] EXCEPTION: (PhutilArgumentUsageException) No pushable remote "origin" exists. Use the "--remote" flag to choose a valid, pushable remote to land changes onto. at [<arcanist>/src/land/ArcanistGitLandEngine.php:34]
arcanist(head=master, ref.master=cc850163f30c), phutil(head=master, ref.master=cc2a3dbf5903)
  #0 ArcanistGitLandEngine::parseArguments() called at [<arcanist>/src/workflow/ArcanistLandWorkflow.php:253]
  #1 ArcanistLandWorkflow::run() called at [<arcanist>/scripts/arcanist.php:394]
```

Would you please let me know how to `arc land` with a `git-svn` repository?

---

**update for a new clue**

[This thread](https://secure.phabricator.com/T13293), found in https://secure.phabricator.com/, might help, but I'm not quite understand.

Comment: I'm currently in exactly this same boat! I have tried to let me do the push manually by passing `--hold` so I could still get arcanist to generate a commit message, but the error was the same.

Comment: @josaphatv It drove me to search over the internet, including the official site of arcanist. However, sad news, nothing really helps. `T.T`

Comment: I think the problem is that arcanist doesn't recognize it as a git-svn repository. Looking through my version of the source, it seems like maybe it would work if your SVN repo was hosted in Diffusion (phabricator). It's not my repo so short of modifying arcanist, I think I'm out of luck.

Comment: @josaphatv Yes, that is. Maybe I would fix this problem later. A workaround is `svn checkout; arc patch --revision <num>; arc commit`, for this present.